# YAML transform a task to another version

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

With Microsoft breaking 2 tasks this week and breaking many pipelines until the fix was released, I am looking into workarounds. I already [documented a few here](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-pipelines-you-broke-our-pipeline/).

One option I'm investigating is the use of a YAML transformation in a Pipeline Decorator.

I've crafted the following YAML transformation to try and replace the version of the `npmAuthenticate@0` task to be exactly and always: `0.200.0`:

```
- steps:
  - ${{ each step in job.steps }}:
    - ${{ if in(step.task.id, 'npmAuthenticate', 'ad884ca2-732e-4b85-b2d3-ed71bcbd2788')}}
      - ${{ each task in step }}:
        - ${{ each pair in task }}:
            ${{ if eq(pair.key, 'version') }}:
              ${{ pair.key }}: 0.200.0
            ${{ if ne(pair.key, 'version') }}: 
              ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
```

But it's not working. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to locally debug these transformers, so the current process of trying out new versions takes forever.

My ask:

- Is this even possible from a pipeline decorator?
- What's wrong with the syntax above?
- Is there a way to debug these things locally?

Here's the [Pipeline Decoractor Context debug information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops#debugging):

```
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6524788Z job={
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6525354Z   "steps": [

...

2023-01-13T09:38:23.6538541Z     {
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6539075Z       "task": {
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6539824Z         "id": "ad884ca2-732e-4b85-b2d3-ed71bcbd2788",
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6540412Z         "name": "npmAuthenticate",
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6541005Z         "version": "0.208.1"
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6542056Z       },
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6542581Z       "env": {},
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6543177Z       "inputs": {
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6545385Z         "workingFile": "npmrc",
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6545995Z         "customEndpoint": ""
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6546519Z       },
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6547100Z       "condition": "succeeded()",
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6547694Z       "continueOnError": false,
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6548265Z       "name": "npmAuthenticate",
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6548890Z       "displayName": "npm Authenticate npmrc",
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6549457Z       "enabled": true
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6549971Z     },

...

2023-01-13T09:38:23.6786723Z   ]
2023-01-13T09:38:23.6787219Z }
2023-01-13T09:38:23.7641252Z ##[section]Finishing: Pipeline decorator context (Windows)
```

No dice either:

```yaml
- steps:
  - ${{ each task in job.steps.*.task }}:
    - ${{ if eq(task.id, 'ad884ca2-732e-4b85-b2d3-ed71bcbd2788')}}
      ${{ if eq(pair.key, 'version') }}:
        ${{ pair.key }}: 0.200.0
      ${{ if ne(pair.key, 'version') }}: 
        ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
```

nor:

```yaml
- steps:
  - ${{ each step in job.steps.* }}:
    - ${{ if eq(step.task.id, 'ad884ca2-732e-4b85-b2d3-ed71bcbd2788')}}:
      - ${{ each prop in step.task }}:
        ${{ if eq(prop.key, 'version') }}:
          ${{ prop.key }}: 0.200.0
        ${{ if ne(prop.key, 'version') }}: 
          ${{ prop.key }}: ${{ prop.value }}
```

The `vss-extension.json`:

```js
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "replace-npmauthenticate-decorator",
    "publisher": "jessehouwing",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "replace-npmauthenticate-decorator",
    "description": "Azure DevOps Extension",
    "categories": [
        "Azure Pipelines"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "default": "logo.png"
    },
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "replace-npmauthenticate-decorator",
            "type": "ms.azure-pipelines.pipeline-decorator",
            "targets": [
                "ms.azure-pipelines-agent-job.pre-job-tasks"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "template": "replace-npmauthenticate-decorator.yml"
            }
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "replace-npmauthenticate-decorator.yml",
            "addressable": true,
            "contentType": "text/plain"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And what if you leave out -steps from the decorator?  In this example it’s also used directly, with jobs.steps.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/pipeline-decorator-context?view=azure-devops#job

Comment: And what about a bunge of plain old print statements to like - script: echo to see where the hack you are... Poor man's debugger 

Comment: can you also paste your vss-extension.json here?

Comment: @promicro I see no way to write any debug statements in the template expansion code. It happens while building the YAML template and outside of my field of view.
extension-json added.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but what I meant. Can peel down the problem by adding echo's in every level of your step in the decorator. Just to check if that part works. So no write from the decorator just adding stuff by the decorato. E.g. does it even come till - ${{ each task in job.steps.*.task }}:? - remove the rest and add - script: echo Injected the decorator

Comment: Another, to obvious I guess, idea. Does your decorator hacking yaml work in your own pre-post-task extension?

Comment: I've given up for now.

Comment: But Jesse if you give up, who do we have left that saves us? Argghhhhhh

Comment: Luckily you haven't :D.

Comment: @promicro if you answer with that it doesn't seem possible I can award you the bounty for trying to help figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to debug a decorator, since the debugging of agents is removed:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2479

Alternatives are:

- split up and peal off the loop
- Use your own pre / post [AzDo task instead](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.pre-post-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented with over 40 different versions of YAML transformations, and tried 8 suggestions by ChatGPT, but ultimately must conclude that this approach does not seem to be viable.

I've seen many different tools to validate YAML structures, but nothing that validates a transform template or allows me to run one with a given context.

Azure DevOps' feedback toward errors is about non-existent. If the YAML is syntactically correct it will say there is an error, but won't tell you what the error is, as such I must conclude that most of my 40 attempts are valid YAML, but that they don't work for some other undisclosed reason.

I've looked most of Azure DevOps Server in IlSpy to see if there is a place I could hook into to locally run the decorator, but so far no such luck, the code that interprets YAML is firmly embedded in the execution context of the pipeline and would require quite a bit if work to run locally out-of-server.